# How can I exclude files from a Visual Studio Web Site project

Tags: visual-studio

In a Visual Studio Web Site type project there is no .csproj file so there is no way to tell Visual Studio to exclude files from the solution. This is a problem for me because my website is huge and Visual Studio takes several minutes to open the solution. I also can not use most of the navigation tools (like Find Usages) and Resharper crashes.

Note that this is not an issue for projects that have a .csproj file where you can right click in the Solution Explorer and choose 'Exclude' to exclude files from the project.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to set the Hidden flag on the files/folders within the file system. When files have the Hidden attribute set Visual Studio ignores them.

To set the Hidden attribute open File Explorer, locate the file or folder, right click and choose 'Properties' then tick the 'Hidden' check box.